# setupwithviewpager can not resolve symbol

Tags: android, android-viewpager, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

```
//** this is MainActivity.
    package com.example.android.kashi;
    import android.os.Bundle;`enter code here`
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.TableLayout;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager()));

            TableLayout tabLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in this line:

```
TableLayout tabLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
```

So you need to cast tabLayout and not TableLayout. here is the fix:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
```

Comment: needs to import `import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;` too